# How to assign ID to the dynamically created rows

Tags: c#, javascript

I am creating rows dynamically in javascript.As the controls in all rows have same id, i need to assign an id to that control when it is creating.can anyone help me how to assign ID to that control
this is my code

```
function AddNewRow(tblrowdetails) {
    var table  =   $("tblrowdetails"); //getting the table id
    var rowCount = table.rows.length; 
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;

            switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                case "text":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                        break;
                case "checkbox":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                        break;
                case "select-one":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                        break;
         }
     }
   }
}
```

Where i need to assign id to the control and how to assign pls help me

Comment: It would be helpful to see `table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML` to know what the "control" is

Comment: In your case statement, just assign a new id before or after you set the value: `newcell.childNodes[0].id = 'newId'`. Some sort of counter based on the rowIndex should do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the way could be

```
...
        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
            // assign id in the form of rX_cY - X,Y being row & column numbers
            $(newcell.childNodes[0]).attr('id', 'r' + rowCount.ToString() + '_c' + i.ToString());

            switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
...
```

Comment: There is no need for `toString()`, the `+` operator will to that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an id to each row, and a class to each control, so you will be able to access to a given control with this query : #myRow .mycontrol.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by 'control' you mean the input you add to a table cell, I suppose `newcell.childNodes[0].id = '[someid]'` should do it? If you want to assign a random id, use something like

```
newcell.childNodes[0].id = 'c' + (Math.floor(Math.random()*10000)).toString(16)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in POJS pretty simply:

```
var table = document.getElementById('tblrowdetails');
var newRow = table.rows[0].cloneNode(true);
var newCells = newRow.cells;  // Use DOM cells collection

/*
  fix the ids and values of controls here
  using your case statement
*/

table.tBodies[0].appendChild(newRow); // Must append to a tBody to keep IE happy
```